# How do I bind an angular 2 event to an svg object?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have the following html:

```
<svg:g *ngFor='let knob of knobs' >
    <svg:path id="arc1" fill="blue" stroke="#446688" stroke-width="1"  
     fill-rule="nonzero" draggable="true" [attr.d]="knob"  
     (drag)="dragKnob(event)" class="draggable"/>
</svg:g>
```

And the script:

```
dragKnob(event: Event): void {
    console.log(event);
}
```

The result is it doesn't execute dragKnob. If I instead use (click) it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag events are not supported on SVG Elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html#RelationshipWithDOM2Events.

if you want to do something while the object is dragged use (mousemove) instead.

```
(mousemove)="dragKnob(event)"
```

And this should write to console:

```
dragKnob(event: Event): void {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yaser, that was the problem! I fixed it combining mousedown, mouseup and mousemove

Answer (score 0):

Just put this events on the HTML and write the the functions inside like 'drag()'

```
  <svg id="robot" version="1.1" viewBox="70 150 150 220" pointer-
     events="visibleFill" 
        **(mouseover)="drag($event)"  
        (mouseleave)="leave($event)"
        (mousedown)="grab($event)" 
        (mouseup)="drop($event)"** 

        class="scaling-svg   robotPath"  >
```